# Does this kind of value setting work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, compression, minify

I'm trying to create code that requires the least number of bytes and that works for all browsers including IE 7.

In this example, the program calls dosomething('x1') and dosomething('x2').

If I have code like this:

```
var items,item,index,count;
items=Array('x1','x2');
count=items.length;
for (index=0;index<count;index++){
item=items[index];
dosomething(item);
}
```

Could I reduce it to this and have it still function exactly the same in all browsers:

```
var a=Array('x1','x2'),c=a.length,i;
for (i=0;i<c;i++){
f(a[i]);
}
```

I understand I changed the variable names and calling function name but my goal is to use the least number of bytes possible in the code to make the code execute.

I'm just not sure if declaring a variable equal to a property of a value from a previous variable in the same list of declarations would actually return correct results.

In other words, does `var a=Array('x1','x2'),c=a.length...` work, or do I have to specifically do `var a=Array('x1','x2');var c=a.length;` to make it work in all browsers including IE 7?

Comment: You can save a few bytes by using: a=['x1','x2']  rather than a=Array('x1','x2')

Answer (score 1):

This is what the Google [Closure Compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) service returned:

```
 var a,b,c,d;a=["x1","x2"];d=a.length;for(c=0​;c<d;c++)b=a[c],dosomething(b);
```

You can find many different Javascript compressors online to automate the process you are hand coding now. Yet, it's always good to [understand how they work](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/compilation_levels?csw=1) as it helps to write code that is better compressed.

As for IE, you can test your code by changing the emulations settings in the IE debugger panel. Just press F12, click the Emulation tab, and adjust the document mode to 7 (IE7).

Hope this is enough to get you started in the right direction.

Comment: Im curious. Why `b=a[c],dosomething(b)` instead of `dosomething(a[c])`?

Comment: @Mike - Good question. The result is the same, but in this case the second method would be better.  Yet, that's not always true.  An array element will often be used multiple times in a function and then it is more efficient to replace it with a single character variable.  The compressors that I've used assume this and automatically replace the array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) from IE 9

```
var items = Array('x1','x2');
items.map(dosomething(item));
```